# .map returns an array of empty objects after getting data with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem when i want an array of collections returned back to me using Mongoose. The problem is that the .map method in the code returns an array of empty objects, but if I log the objects individually in the .map everything is fine. Why is this happening?

```
const patients = doctor.patients.map(async patient => {
  try {
    const patientObj = await Patient.findOne({ username: patient });
    patient = patientObj;
    patient.jwt = undefined;
    patient.__v = undefined;
    console.log(patient);  // This works just fine, logs the object the right way

    return patient;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
console.log(patients); // This logs [{}, {}, {}]
```

Comment: 1. You have no `return` in your mapping function. 2. You pass an async callback so you'd get an array of promises back regardless of what code you have.

Comment: Also in your mongoose schema you can add (select: false), so you do not have to set patient.password to undefined

  password: {type: String, select: false},

Comment: Moreover, it seems like you just want a list of patients for a specific doctor?

Comment: @Fullhdpixel that is correct. Also, it doesn't seem to work after adding "return" either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to have an array of patients which are related to one doctor. Try this solution.

```js
Patient.find({
    username: { $in: doctor.patients }
}, (err: any, patients) => {
    console.log("patients  " + patients)
})
```

In your Patient model add (select: false), so you do not have to set every field to undefined https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-select

Comment: Link to current docco https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-select